# "if [ -z $variable ]" in a shell script is not recognising my variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables, sh

When I run the following script it keeps defaulting to the else statement and I'm not sure why. I have even included an **echo $workflow** which showed me the name that I was expecting to see but it still keeps defaulting to the else statement.

I've tried including an **export namecheck=$workflow** to see if that was the issue but it still gave the same end result

```
#!/bin/sh

read -p "Enter the workflow name: " workflowName

workflowName=${workflowName}

curl --request GET --url https://website.com > workflowjson.txt

workflow=$(jq -r .metadata.name workflowjson.txt)

echo $workflow

if [ -z "$workflow" ] then
    echo "Workflow is Valid" 
else
    echo "Workflow is not valid" 
fi
```

Comment: `echo $workflow` is unwise.  You should be careful to quote variable expansions where there is any risk of the expansion being further interpreted by the shell (pathname expansion, word splitting, ...).  Thus, `echo "$workflow"` would be much safer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank you, that's one to look out for in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man test` shows

> `-z STRING`  the length of `STRING` is zero

The code outputs `Workflow is Valid` when the workflow is empty.

Switch the `then` and `else` parts, or negate the condition (use `-n` instead of `-z`).

Comment: of course it is! I was being silly...smh. Thank You!

Answer (score -6):

try taking the quotes out around workflow and put then in a separate line

```
if [ -z $workflow ]
then
  echo "Workflow is Valid" 
else
  echo "Workflow is not valid"
fi
```

Comment: Removing the quotes around variables in `[` is a bad idea. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_-n_.24foo_.5D_or_.5B_-z_.24foo_.5D

Comment: ... and there is no reason to think that doing so would improve the specific behavior the OP asked about.

Comment: You still will need to invert the echo messages or negate the condition or use -n as choroba suggested above.